# How to use Electron webview with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, electron

Has anyone had luck creating a vue application that utilizes Electron webviews? I have the following setup, but when I run the window is blank.

```
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webviewTag: true,
    width: 1276, 
    height: 800, 
    frame: false, 
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    center: true, 
    movable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
}

Then in my component.
```

```
     <webview id="foo" src="https://www.youtube.com/" style="display:inline-flex; width:640px; height:480px"></webview>
```

Comment: What does the console in DevTools say?

Comment: Console is blank and it renders as <webview data-v-b27f0436="" src="http://nativescript-vue.org/" style="display: inline-flex; width: 640px; height: 480px;"></webview>, but is an empty box.

Comment: Which url is this browserWindow loading? Maybe index.html? And the components just including this webview tag?

Comment: It's loading app://./index.html and it's loading all of the other components just fine except for the webview one, which again is a blank card.

Answer (score 0):

Move `webviewTag: true`, to webPreferences